# Knockout performance issues with arrays having dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I'm using knockout.repeat to draw dynamic column array with following data:

```
var columns = ko.observableArray([
    new Column(1),
    new Column(2),
    new Column(3),
    new Column(4),
    new Column(5)
});

var array = ko.observableArray([1..95]);
```

Data is assigned the following way with knockout mapping:

```
mappingConfig = {
    create: function (options) {
        return new Row(options.data);
    }
};
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingCOnfig, array);
```

In the following way:

```
<div data-bind="repeat: {foreach: array, item: '$row'}">
        <div data-bind="repeat: {foreach: column, item: '$col'}">
            <input data-bind="value: $row()[$col().Name]"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue I'm having is that it takes nearly **30 seconds to render 95 rows with 6 columns**.

- **How can I troubleshoot the performance?**
- Are there any tools?
- Are there any guide lines how to maximize performance in similar
  scenarios?

Chrome timeline:
[image]

**UPDATE:** I was under pressure, so I re-wrote the tables in reactjs, which solved a lot of issues and is rendering only 1.5 sec.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @RoyJ Working with `Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m`

Comment: I remember running to an issue like this.  For ~1500 rows of data, it took minutes to add/remove sets of rows.  I don't remember what I did exactly to alleviate it but it think what it ultimately boiled down to was that you had to minimize the amount of time was spent creating dom elements.  A lot of the time was spent in the GC which killed it.  In my case, a lot of the dom elements were being recreated because the data objects I bound to them were constantly being rebuilt from scratch.  Also updates need to be done in a single batch, do not update individually.

Comment: @JeffMercado Attached Chrome timeline - it seems that the most time spent is in scripting rather then rendering and painting.

Comment: It's sad that in the end you had to choose another framework/ lib to solve the problem..

Answer (score -1):

You can use Chrome's dev tools to troubleshoot preformance, specifically [Profiles](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#javascript-performance), [Network](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance) and [Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#timeline) in your case.

Please include a JSFiddle with a reproduce and it'll be easier for use to work through the problem.

Comment: More on profiling in Chrome:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: I'm really not sure where to look at and what to investigate - see updated post with timeline.